# c# unit test entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have pain to understand how to unit test with EF in a concret exemple.
thing seem half explained everywhere.

in my real word exemple i have a class with method.

```
namespace Genkai_wpf
{
    public class CustomClass 
    {
        public UNITY_DB_PRODEntities12 Genkai_db = new UNITY_DB_PRODEntities12();
        public static string[] probtpRegex;
        public static string[] audiensRegex;
        public static string OUDestructionProbtp;
        public static string OUDestructionAudiens;


       public void Init()
        {
            OUDestructionProbtp = Genkai_db.Config.First(x => x.Properties == "OUDestructionProbtp").Value;
            OUDestructionAudiens = Genkai_db.Config.First(x => x.Properties == "OUDestructionAudiens").Value;
            probtpRegex = Genkai_db.Config.First(x => x.Properties == "Regex_Probtp").Value.Split(',');
            audiensRegex = Genkai_db.Config.First(x => x.Properties == "Regex_Audiens").Value.Split(',');


        }
}
```

this code work find in code and retrieve some regex stored in my db config table.

but in unitest i can't test this ini methode cuz EF refuse with random error on all my  different try.

here shunk of code in my unitTest.cs

```
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private TestContext testContextInstance;

        CustomClass PROBTP = new CustomClass();

      public UnitTest1()
        {
            PROBTP.Init();
        }
}
}
```

i call the `CustomClass.init()` methode from  `public class UnitTest1`

and get error where it can't create an instance of my EF.

for better understanding try use my code in response thanks.

ps: i heard of moking/effort/repository
but i don't get it and don't even know what is realy the best methode...

the error in unitest : UNITY_DB_PRODEntities12 is the EF from main project
in unitest name differente

```
<add name="UNITY_DB_PRODEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=M35824\MSQL32BIT;initial catalog=UNITY_DB_PROD;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Nom du test :   UT_Domain
FullName de test :  UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.UT_Domain
Source de test :    c:\Users\PB19150\Documents\£DOI-DIT-BIM\Developpement\DEV-C#\Genkai_Client_32\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs : ligne 48
Sortie du test :    Échec
Durée du test : 0:00:00

Message de résultat  :  Impossible de créer une instance de la classe UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1. Erreur : System.InvalidOperationException: La chaîne de connexion 'UNITY_DB_PRODEntities12' est introuvable dans le fichier de configuration de l'application..
StackTrace de résultat  :
à System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()
   à System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   à System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   à System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   à System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   à System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   à System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   à Genkai_wpf.CustomClass.Init() dans c:\Users\PB19150\Documents\£DOI-DIT-BIM\Developpement\DEV-C#\Genkai_Client_32\Genkai_wpf\Control\CustomClass.cs:ligne 26
   à UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1..ctor() dans c:\Users\PB19150\Documents\£DOI-DIT-BIM\Developpement\DEV-C#\Genkai_Client_32\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:ligne 27

***i try then to give both conection string the same name but get an other error.***

Nom du test :   UT_Domain
FullName de test :  UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.UT_Domain
Source de test :    c:\Users\PB19150\Documents\£DOI-DIT-BIM\Developpement\DEV-C#\Genkai_Client_32\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs : ligne 48
Sortie du test :    Échec
Durée du test : 0:00:00

Message de résultat  :
Impossible de créer une instance de la classe UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1. Erreur : System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Le schéma spécifié n'est pas valide. Erreurs : 
Model1.csdl(3,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Autorisation' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(10,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Config' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(17,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.final_full_data' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(58,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.final_McAfee' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(71,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.final_probtp_user' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(83,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Real_Time_Update' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(89,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Stat_Transact' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(98,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Synchronized_crossdomain_AD' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(107,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Update_Status' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(114,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.DCAI_ET' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(124,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.debug_final' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(134,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.debug_FPAC' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(144,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.debug_McAfee' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(154,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.final_bmc_fpac' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(174,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Final_DCAI' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(188,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.FPAC_Debug' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(198,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Genkai_Delete' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(214,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Temporary_BASEIP' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(289,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Temporary_DCAI' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(303,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Temporary_full_data' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(554,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Check_Transact' a déjà été défini.
Model1.csdl(563,4) : erreur 0019: Chaque nom de type dans un schéma doit être unique. Le nom de type 'UNITY_DB_PRODModel.Record' a déjà été défini..
StackTrace de résultat  :
à System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModelOption, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, ItemCollection itemCollection, Boolean throwOnError)
   à System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)
   à System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadEdmItemCollection(MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
   à System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__0(String k)
   à System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   à System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader)
   à System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace(DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions)
   à System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace()
   à System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()
   à System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   à System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   à System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   à System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   à System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   à System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   à System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   à System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   à System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   à Genkai_wpf.CustomClass.Init() dans c:\Users\PB19150\Documents\£DOI-DIT-BIM\Developpement\DEV-C#\Genkai_Client_32\Genkai_wpf\Control\CustomClass.cs:ligne 26
   à UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1..ctor() dans c:\Users\PB19150\Documents\£DOI-DIT-BIM\Developpement\DEV-C#\Genkai_Client_32\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:ligne 27

***both conection string in both project are in app.config . 
the first error say it can't find an instance of UNITY_DB_PRODEntities12 wich make sence since its in first project. in unittest name is differente its UNITY_DB_PRODEntities1 not 12
the second error when i try give same name say that all my table are duplicated.***

Answer (score 1):

If your unit test project is separated project (it looks like), you need to add `Entity Framework` from `Nuget` to **unit test project**, as well as **copy all connection strings section there**

Hope it helps

If possible, please include "random error" in your question.

Comment: i did add already but its the *EF instance of the other project who is caled

Comment: if i give the same name of EF conection string on both project the error change and i get conflict so

Comment: @Zwan where do you store your connection strings? Is this inside app.config/web.config?

Comment: @Zwan: Sorry I don't understand French so I cannot read your edited error message. Could you help me translate it to English?

Comment: both conection string in both project are in app.config . the first error say it can't find an instance of  UNITY_DB_PRODEntities12 wich make sence since its in first project. in unittest name is differente its  UNITY_DB_PRODEntities1    not 12

Comment: @Zwan: you need to use same name in both projects (`UNITY_DB_PRODEntities12`)

Comment: it don't work look error 2. it tell my base table already exist

Comment: @zwan: It's a different error already. Is your code running normally in main application? Can you translate your exception message?

Comment: yes it does run well. just an error where it search  UNITY_DB_PRODEntities12 and when i had it it not happy cuz doublon....

Answer (score 0):

well i resolved this myself.
my main error was to had the entitity framework.dll manually in the unittest project.

all i had to do is importing entityframework with nugets and now its working.